# Refresh all fragments content after returning from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a drop down (connected with db) in every fragment (4 fragments in one fragment activity).

Problem is that when I come back from AddNew intent the drop down list still contains the previous data. All I want is to refresh the data in drop down(s).

I have tried writing the following code but it gets stuck in a loop calling it self again and again.

```
public void OnResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    this.finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: Tried starting AddNew using startActivityForResult and then set the result in AddNew activity and catch the result in MainActivity using onActivityResult?

Comment: No I didn't knew about any such thing. How do we catch result?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`s of your `Fragment`s when you want to refresh the data.